# Is there a sequence or order to perform Shatkarmas?

Tags: yoga, kriyayoga, pranayama, hatha-yoga

In the yoga, as a physical body cleansing mechanism, we have Shatkarmas - 6 kriyas.
Namely -

1. Neti,
2. Douti,
3. Nauli,
4. Basti,
5. Kapalabhathi Pranayama,
6. Trataka.

I would like to know is there a order in which these kriyas needs to be performed as per yoga shastra?
Like, I have heard Bhastrika Pranayama needs to be performed after Neti. And it makes logical sense, because, after the Neti, water residue would be there in nasal passage. So doing Bastrika pranayama after that helps in removing that residual water content from the nasal passage.

Likewise, is there an order/sequence for all the Shatkriyas?

Answer (score 1):

The right approach for shat karmas is never mentioned. So once a person goes to a realised guru, he decides which one of the  shat karmas are to be done based on the Prakriti of the yogi in question.
Usually general practices include neti, which can be done to balance the vata and kapha and it can be followed after kunjal kriya or Vamana dhauti. These two karmas often are enough to balance the Doshas and further help the yogi to start his sadhana in yoga.

## yogibips